# How to display the categories on page using shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, shortcode

I am trying to display the categories name on my page but it's not displaying.  I am using the below code and I added the shortcode `gridCategories` on my page. I am getting only `array`

```
function createGridCategories(){
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0, // change to 1 to hide categores not having a single post
) );
var_dump($categories);
return $categories;
}
add_shortcode( 'gridCategories', 'createGridCategories');
```

I tried this also

```
$categories = get_the_category();
var_dump($categories);
```

I added a shortcode like this in textblock

[image]
But still, I am not getting any output on my page. Is there any issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any issue with my code?

Yes, there is. [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) *returns an array* of terms, e.g. [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects or a list of term IDs, so you can't simply do `return $categories;`.

Instead,

- For a basic list such as `Foo category, Bar category, etc.` (i.e. no category links), you can simply set the `fields` parameter to `names` which then gives you a list of category names:

  ```php
  function createGridCategories() {
      $categories = get_categories( array(
          'fields'     => 'names',
          'hide_empty' => 0,
          // other args here
      ) );

      return implode( ', ', $categories );
  }
  ```
- Or you can manually loop through the terms and just build the markup/HTML to your own liking:

  ```php
  function createGridCategories() {
      $categories = get_categories( array(
          'hide_empty' => 0,
          // other args here
      ) );

      $list = '';

      foreach ( $categories as $term ) {
          $url = get_category_link( $term );
          $list .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
      }

      return "<ul>$list</ul>";
  }
  ```
- Or alternatively (for a list/`UL` like the above), you can use [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/):

  ```php
  function createGridCategories() {
      $list = wp_list_categories( array(
          'taxonomy'   => 'category',
          'hide_empty' => 0,
          'echo'       => 0,
          'title_li'   => '',
          // other args here
      ) );

      return "<ul>$list</ul>";
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. Thank you so much. Appreciate for giving me a valuable information. Upvote from my side.

Comment: I tried all three options. All are working. I need a small help in the second one. How can I use UL LI ?

Comment: Just do `$list[] = '<li><a ...>...</a></li>'` and `return "<ul>$list</ul>"` like in the revised code.

Comment: Yes,It's working,  I also remove the comma from implode.

Comment: Or you may instead define `$list` as a string (`$list = ''`), then use `$list .= '<li>...</li>'`, and remove the `$list = implode()` there. (PS: I've actually removed that comma)

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I am working on the post grid. I have to show the category and then click on any category then display all the posts related to that category below. I can't use any plugin.

Comment: Glad I could help :), and I've changed the `$list` in the *second code* to a string as I mentioned before. Cheers.

Comment: @SallyCJ, shouldn't it be `$term->slug` instead to display the name of the categories? `$term->name` returns the name of the post.

Comment: @Motivated `$term->slug` is the slug of the category, so if the name is `Foo bar`, then that becomes the value of `$term->name`, whereas `$term->slug` would be `foo-bar`. See [`WP_Term` in GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php#L28-L42).

Comment: @SallyCJ, that's what I'd expect. For some bizarre reason, it returns the name of the post instead.

Comment: @Motivated that sounded like a theme/plugin issue, so you can try deactivating plugins and see if the same issue persists. But you should post a new question, instead of discussing it here. ✌